# Query to find employees with no review or last review over 3 months ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue with SQL part of my program. I have two tables Review and Employee. Employees can add reviews to each other but only once in every three months. Review table has this structure:

```
| ID | PerfomanceRating| Comment| ReviewDate| EmployeeID|
```

My goal is to retrieve all employees who has their latest review done more than 3 months ago. So my guess was that I need to get current date, subtract three months from it and compare to the `MAX()` date of each employee and if it is bigger - retrieve that employee from the database. Query:

```
SELECT Employee.ID, (FName + ' ' + LName) as Name, Review.ReviewDate, Email
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Review ON Employee.ID = Review.EmployeeId 
WHERE SupervisorID = @empId
GROUP BY ReviewDate,Employee.ID,FName,LName,Email
HAVING ReviewDate IS NULL OR MAX(ReviewDate) < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
```

IS NULL - I have it here because employee can be freshly added and might not have any reviews. My problem is that this query gives me back employees with old reviews as well. Mean if employee had a review 4 months ago it will retrieve it ignoring my check for `MAX(ReviewDate)`.

I feel that I'm missing something here but cannot get what exactly.

Example:
We have two employees in a table, one has two reviews and one has only one old review:

```
1   |   ReviewTest3 ReviewTest3 |   2019-04-30 00:00:00.0000000
2   |   ReviewTest2 ReviewTest2 |   2019-01-11 00:00:00.0000000 
3   |   ReviewTest2 ReviewTest2 |   2020-05-11 00:00:00.0000000
```

So MY query should show me only

```
1   |   ReviewTest3 ReviewTest3 |   2019-04-30 00:00:00.0000000
```

AS ReviewTest2 ReviewTest2   has recent review. In my case it is

```
1   |   ReviewTest3 ReviewTest3 |   2019-04-30 00:00:00.0000000
2   |   ReviewTest2 ReviewTest2 |   2019-01-11 00:00:00.0000000
```

ReviewTest2 is also shown as it has review with an old date

Comment: I recommend reading [tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) as it will result is better/faster answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of query keep the joins out of it... you're not looking to *join* the information, you just want to aggregate it, and use it for filtering. I find sub-queries far more straight-forward in such situations e.g.

```
select ID, (FName + ' ' + LName) as [Name], ReviewDate, Email
from (
  select ID, SupervisorID, FName, LName, Email
    , (select max(R.ReviewDate) from dbo.Review R where R.EmployeeID = E.ID) ReviewDate
  from dbo.Employee E
) E
where SupervisorID = @empId
and (ReviewDate is null or ReviewDate < dateadd(month, -3, current_timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

use window function `row_number()`.

```
select
    ID,
    Name,
    ReviewDate,
    Email
from
(
    SELECT 
        Employee.ID, 
        (FName + ' ' + LName) as Name, 
        Review.ReviewDate, 
        Email,
        row_number() over (partition by Employee.ID order by convert(date, Review.ReviewDate) desc) as rnk 
    FROM Employee 
    LEFT JOIN Review ON Employee.ID = Review.EmployeeId 
    WHERE SupervisorID = @empId
    AND (Review.ReviewDate is null  or ReviewDate < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY ReviewDate,Employee.ID,FName,LName,Email
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Good try but miss the target. Still gives me not what I wanted. Example:
I have employee with two reviews : 01/01/2020 and 05/05/2020   . You query still show me record with an old review , and it shouldnt because this employee already have new review which was done recently. See what I mean ?

Comment: @MikeBashkatov what is the data type of  `Review.ReviewDate` ?

Comment: @zealous  datetime2

Comment: @MikeBashkatov you have to convert into `date` and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared sample data and tested in SQL Server.

```sql
DECLARE @employee table(Id int, FName varchar(30), LName varchar(30), Email varchar(255),SuperVisorId int)
Declare @review table (ID int, PerfomanceRating varchar(30), Comment varchar(30), ReviewDate datetime2, EmployeeID int)

insert into @employee VALUES(1,'Murugan','R','abc@xyz.com',999),(2,'Kandan','V','xyz@abc.com',999),(3,'Mark','Z','mark@mark.com',999)
insert into @review values(1,'review1','review1','2020-01-01',1),(2,'review2','review2','2020-05-05',1),
(3,'review1','review1','2020-01-01',2);

SELECT oe.ID, (oe.FName + ' ' + oe.LName) as Name, r.ReviewDate, Email
FROM @Employee AS oe
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT MAX(r.ReviewDate) FROM @review as r WHERE r.EmployeeId = oe.ID 
GROUP BY r.EmployeeId
HAVING MAX(r.ReviewDate) < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) 
) as r(reviewDate)
WHERE SupervisorId = 999
-- Get Employees without review
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, (FName + ' ' + LName) as Name, NULL AS ReviewDate, Email
FROM @Employee as oe
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT EmployeeId FROM @review WHERE EmployeeID = oe.Id)
AND SuperVisorId =999
```

**Result set**

```
+----+----------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| ID |   Name   |         ReviewDate          |     Email     |
+----+----------+-----------------------------+---------------+
|  2 | Kandan V | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | xyz@abc.com   |
|  3 | Mark Z   | NULL                        | mark@mark.com |
+----+----------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```